# Running docker with host user - bad password?

Tags: docker

After some research I was able to run docker with my host user using:

```
docker run -it \
  -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd \
  -v /etc/group:/etc/group \
  -v /etc/sudoers:/etc/sudoers \
  -v $HOME:$HOME \
  --user=$(id -u):$(id -g) \
  ...
```

My problem now is that my password is somehow different than host. (i.e when I do su - my-user I get wrong password error).

This is problematic because now user can't run sudo unless he is a passwordless sudoer.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: one yes no question, are you trying to run docker containers in user space that requiring root privileges?

Comment: You generally don't need `sudo` in Docker, and it interacts badly with typical workflows because there often isn't a controlling terminal.  In your Dockerfile specify `USER root` (which is the default), or from the host use a `-u root` or `-u 0` option to `docker run` or `docker exec`.  Also remember than anything you do inside the container is lost when you `docker rm` the container: installing software and similar administrative tasks inside running containers is usually discouraged.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/etc/shadow` keeps information about user passwords, so you need to mount it as well. For example:

```
sudo docker run --rm -ti \
  -v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd \
  -v /etc/group:/etc/group \
  -v /etc/sudoers:/etc/sudoers \
  -v /etc/shadow:/etc/shadow \
  -v $HOME:$HOME \
  --user=$(id -u):$(id -g) \
  ...
```

Comment: This works, but I had to add `--group-add sudo` instead of mounting `/etc/group`.